# How to set tab indent for function arguments in PyCharm?

Tags: python, pycharm, styling

Instead of double indent **for function arguments**

```
def foo(
        name
):
    print('hello ' + name)
```

I would like to use single indent:

```
def foo(
    name
):
    print('hello ' + name)
```

=> How can I tell PyCharm to use single indent for function arguments?

Unfortunately, under

```
Settings => Editor => Code Style => Python => Tabs and Indents
```

there does not seem to be an extra option for it:

[image]

As an alternative: what is the rational behind using extra indent for the arguments?

Comment: Of course for Python [black](https://github.com/psf/black) is the de-facto standard formatter, and can be [integrated directly into PyCharm](https://black.readthedocs.io/en/stable/integrations/editors.html#pycharm-intellij-idea)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*Facepalm* ... its the option "Continuation indent".